# How to open url link by using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiapplication, openurl

i want to go to a url by clicking on button. I tried using 'UISharedapplication'and also through the method below mentioned but none works. Please help.
Thanks.

```
@IBAction func Displayurl(_ sender: Any) {

    UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(NSURL (string: "http://www.apple.com")! as URL)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The issue is that `UIApplication`'s `canOpenURL()` method simply returns *whether* a URL *can* be opened, and does not actually open the URL. Once you've determined whether the URL can be opened (by calling `canOpenURL()`, as you have done), you must then call `open()` on the shared `UIApplication` instance to actually open the URL. This is demonstrated below:

```
if let url = URL(string: "http://www.apple.com") {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
    }
}
```

[`open()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open) also takes an optional `completionHandler` argument with a single `success` parameter that you can choose to implement to determine if the URL was successfully opened.

Comment: let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url!)
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)  
solved this too by adding 'Safariservice' framework. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

`canOpenURL(_:)` method is used whether there is an installed app that can handle the url scheme. To open the resource of the specified URL use the `open(_:options:completionHandler:)` method. As for example

```
 if let url = URL(string: "apple.com") {
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
        }
    }
```

For more info check the documentation here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622961-openurl